# Could not deduce (Enum a) arising from the arithmetic sequence `(x - n + 1) .. x'

Tags: haskell, syntax

when I try to compile this piece of code

```
prod [] = 1
prod (x:xs) = x * prod xs

ff :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
ff x n = prod [(x - n + 1) .. x]
```

I get following error:

```
a.hs:5:15:
    Could not deduce (Enum a)
     arising from the arithmetic sequence `(x - n + 1) .. x'
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the type signature for ff :: Num a => a -> a -> a
      at a.hs:5:1-32
    Possible fix:
      add (Enum a) to the context of
        the type signature for ff :: Num a => a -> a -> a
    In the first argument of `prod', namely `[(x - n + 1) .. x]'
    In the expression: prod [(x - n + 1) .. x]
    In an equation for `ff': ff x n = prod [(x - n + 1) .. x]
```

what is wrong with this code? When I substitute `Double` for a everything is all right.

Comment: `Num` is not an `Enum`, as you can have `Num` types that would be hard to enumerate, like `Complex`.

Comment: Remove the type signature for `ff` and see what type the compiler deduces.

Comment: @augustss How do I check what compiler deduces?

Comment: Remove the type signature and turn on the warning about missing type signatures.  Or use ghci.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[i .. j]` is shorthand for `enumFromTo i j`. `enumFromTo` is part of the [`Enum`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t%3aEnum) typeclass, and not part of [`Num`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t%3aNum) (you still need `Num` to use `+` and `-` though).

So you need to say that `a` implements `Enum` as well as implementing `Num`:

```
ff :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> a -> a
ff x n = prod [(x - n + 1) .. x]
```

It works with `Double` because `Double` implements both these typeclasses.

Answer (score 2):

In order for `[x .. y]` to work, the result type doesn't need to be a `Num` instance at all (e.g., `['A'..'Z']` works just fine). It needs to be an `Enum` instance. Just add `Enum` to the type signature.

It works with `Double` since `Double` has both instances.

Answer (score 1):

`ff :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a -> a

ff x n = prod [(x - n + 1) .. x]`